# Unable to perform Tukey's HSD test on interaction

Tags: r, tukey

I have a significant interaction and would like to perform a Tukey's HSD test on it, however, the examples I've found online don't seem to work for me.

My data:

```
>dput(head(dataAvgSucCI))
structure(list(Collection = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Irrigation = 
structure(c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Rate1", "Rate2", "Rate3", "Rate4", 
"Rate5"), class = "factor"), meanSuc = c(0.585416666666667, 0.5032, 
0.61375, 0.602775, 0.688466666666667, 0.545133333333333), ab = 
structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 2L), .Label = c("1.Rate1", "2.Rate1", "1.Rate2", 
"2.Rate2", "1.Rate3", "2.Rate3", "1.Rate4", "2.Rate4", "1.Rate5", 
"2.Rate5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Collection", drop = TRUE, indices 
= list(0:4, 5L), group_sizes = c(5L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = 
structure(list(Collection = 1:2), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", 
vars = "Collection", drop = TRUE)
```

What I am trying to do:

```
require(multcomp) 
intSucCI <- with(dataAvgSucCI, interaction(Collection, Irrigation)) 
sucCIHSD.aov <- aov(meanSuc ~ Collection*Irrigation, data=dataAvgSucCI) 
summary(sucCIHSD.aov) 
sucCIHSD.glht <- glht(sucCIHSD.aov, linfct = mcp(intSucCI = "Tukey"))
```

Error code, occurs on last line of previous code:

> Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : 
>         Variable(s) ‘intSucCI’ have been specified in ‘linfct’ but cannot be found in ‘model’!`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the library TukeyC?.

```r
library(TukeyC)
data(FE)

dad = FE$dfm

mod = aov(y ~ blk + N*P*K, dad)

#Studing K within N0 and P0.
tk = TukeyC(mod, which = 'N:P:K', fl1 = 1, fl2 = 1)
summary(tk)
plot(tk)

See help(TukeyC) to more details!
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, could you please share how this would work with my data specifically? I am not sure how to apply mine to what you put, but the code seems promising. Thanks!

Comment: mod = aov(meanSuc ~ Collection*Irrigation,dataAvgSucCI); tk = TukeyC(mod,which='Collection:Irrigation',fl1= 1)#Irrigation within collection 1;plot(tk);summary(tk)

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful and I will definitely use it. Do you know if it's also possible to do Tukey's on all of the irrigation treatments together at the same time? So that it still groups them into 10 treatments of Irrigation by Collection, but does the Tukey's analysis on the values of all 10 at once.

Comment: You can use the apply function or a loop (for). Assuming Collection has ten levels. So, comparing the irrigations for all levels of Collections has: tk=list();for(i in 1:10)tk[[i]] = TukeyC(mod, which='Collection:Irrigation', fl1=i); sapply(tk,summary). Is it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I did a great job of explaining what I meant. Collection has 2 values, and Irrigation has 5, so there are 10 total treatments. Instead of comparing the 5 irrigation values within each collection, I would like to compare all 10 combinations at once. Is that possible?

Comment: ONE: This does not make sense speaking theoretically. When significant interaction is detected, it is because the levels of one factor behave differently from within each level of the other factor. Therefore it is recommended in this case, study the Irrigation factor from each level of Collection and vice-versa.

Comment: TWO:If you still want to insist on such a misconception, you can create a factor (intSucCI) from the interaction and use it in the function. For example: dataAvgSucCI$intSucCI <- with(dataAvgSucCI, interaction(Collection, Irrigation)); mod2 = aov(meanSuc ~ intSucCI, dataAvgSucCI); tk2 = TukeyC (mod2, which = 'intSucCI'); summary (tk2); plot (tk2). In this case, it is very likely that there are overlaps of averages and therefore, I recommend using Scott-Knott. See the library(ScottKnott). The procedure (input) is the same as TukeyC.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the response. I had a meeting with my advisor and brought this up. They were okay with doing it the original way you posted, separating by collection. However, when I do so, each treatment is given a different letter, even when they are very close together. Is this incorrect? For example, in Collection two, rates 1 and 3 are almost the same value, yet they are given different letters. This seems like it is putting the treatments in order, but isn't actually fitting them into reasonable groups. Do you know if I am making a mistake somewhere? Thanks again

Comment: Please, do cv(mod)!

Comment: Thanks! Here is my result when I do that: `cv(mod); cv; 
NaN`. I'm not very experienced with R, does that clarify anything?

Comment: cv is a function that return the coefficient of variation of model. If you have mod = aov(.....), then make cv(mod). Starting the answer of your question (Is this incorrect), I would say it depends. It is unlikely that there is anything wrong. Many researchers do not understand the essence of statistics. They are fond of numerical quantities and forget that every conclusion is based on probability. If the differences are very small among their averages and yet the Tukey test points out differences is because there is a high probability of actually being different.

Comment: The Tukey test so far is the most powerful of the multiple comparison tests with respect to type I error rate (reject H0 when this is true). That is, it will only reject H0 when there is in fact a probability (1-alpha) of the means are distinct. When the test of Tukey points differences between 2.33 and 2.32 some things come to mind. First: The experiment was very well conducted, which culminated in a very low experimental error. Second: 
There is no more space to continue my archery.